# Как закешировать данные полученные по api?

Tags: php

Настраиваю интеграцию с сервисом доставки.

**на клиенте** при вводе данные отправляются по ajax на сервер.

**на сервере** при получении данных всегда идет один и тот же запрос к API, с получением списка городов. Список всегда полный.

После того как массив получен, производится поиск по массиву на содержание в нем прилетевшей с клиента строки.

Затем в клиент отдается отфильтрованный массив.

**Вопрос:** можно ли как то при вводе данных с клиента, делать однократный запрос к  API записывать полученный массив в переменную, а при втором и последующем запросе, при вводе данных, проверять на наличие содержимого в этой переменной, если есть то искать по нему.

Сейчас при каждом обращении при вводе постоянно идет запрос API а ответ там не самый быстрый.

Вариант с тем, чтобы выкачать данные и записать в файл и обновлять его при обновлении данных у поставщика услуг не подходит, так как нет информации о том когда происходит обновление.

может быть есть вариант на какое то время сохранить полученные данные например чтобы переменная жила день.

Comment: Для информации, [Как работает РНР](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke). Это чтобы не возникало вопросов, про "записывать полученный массив в переменную". Хотя технически, конечно, вопрос решается именно записью в переменную, понимание все равно нужно

Comment: А в чем проблема? Получаете данные по апи, кешируете . При дальнейших запросах проверяете. если ли данные в кеше, если есть - отдаете оттуда, если нету - кешируете, и отдаете данные

Comment: @manowartop проблема в том как кешировать? когда сбрасывать кеш, а когда нет? как сервер узнает, что данные устарели что список обновился.

Comment: Буду, наверное, при загрузке страницы делать отдельный запрос, который будет записывать в js переменную. И производить поиск по этому массиву.

Comment: Первая же [ссылка](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) из запроса к гуглу "закешировать данные php" ответит на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @NikolajSarry, вижу что данные выбираются из базы)) проблема та же, как поддерживать базу в актуальном состоянии)
обычный хостинг ограничивает меня в использовании memcache

Comment: Спорить не в коем случае не хочу, так как мало что понимаю в этом

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, так как насколько я помню, php запускается заного при каждом запросе к странице, в отличии от node

Comment: Кешируйте на 12 часов да и все, каждый день будут новые данные

Comment: что такое "кешируйте на 12 часов" чем, можете подробнее описать метод кеширования конкретной переменной в php?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, а что мешает заменить запрос к базе на запрос api? не вижу никакой проблемы. На хостинге смотрите позволяет ли он использовать что-то  из: apc, xcache, opcache, если нет, то никакое кеширование вы не сделаете. А вообще странно при нынешних ценах на VPS использовать shared-хостинги.

Comment: @NikolajSarry можете посоветовать достойный по соотношению цена качество?

Comment: Прочитайте вот тут. 
Есть параметр, отвечающий за то, на сколько кешируется переменная
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.apc-store.php

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов данный вопрос выходит за рамки данной площадки.

Comment: Первый `api` -> запись в файл. Следующий `api` -> пощупали дату модификации файла. Устраивает ? [вернули содержимое] : [выполнили `api` && записали файл]